# Put 2 FLV movies next to each other with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Im new to ffmpeg and the documentations are overwhelming.

Would like to "Glue" 2 FLV movies together (ascii art does not work here so)

[ 1 ]  [ 2 ]

[1][2] <=  create 1 new movie with the 2 video's playing next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging the docs this seems to work:

```
ffmpeg -i stream1.mp4 -i stream2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, pad=iw*2:ih[bg]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg]; [bg][fg]overlay=w; amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3" output.mp4
```

Comment: That example looks familiar...

Comment: Its yours? I just found it somewhere but can't recall sorry if its your and i missed crediting

Answer (score 1):

Please consider converting them to mp4 (since Flash supports it and its more compact)
The use this:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Taken from [Concatenating media files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files)

Comment: Ah great! is it also possible to make sure they are both the same length? perhaps use the shortest movie and limit the longer one to that? I test and accept

Comment: Same duration you mean?

Comment: Yes the same duration, so movie1 = 0:30, movie2 = 0:32, how to combine them both and make the movie quit at 0:30 ( so 2 seconds of movie 2 get lost )

Comment: To select just the relevant portions of the video, I used the -ss (start/seek position) and -t (time/duration) flags, e.g.:

ffmpeg -f h264 -i input-video-file.264 -ss 180 -t 8 output-video-file.mp4

The above example takes 8 seconds of the input video starting at the 3-minute (180-second) mark.

Comment: Sorry I didn't test correctly your answer is not solution to problem, it puts the movies *behind* each other i want them to be tiled next to each other.